Get all asssociated stories with a epic programatically
can some one help me with this request.
I am trying to use atlassian python api and rest api to list all tasks associated with a epic. unfortunately  i am unable to do it. does some one have a working piece of code?
I tried this:
jira = Jira(url=os.getenv('JIRA_URL'), username=os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME'), password=os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD'),
            cloud=True)

jira.get_issues_for_epic(board_id = 1, epic_id = epic_key)

but i am getting 400 http error
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
i even tried out searching using rest api but not working.

I didn't play with the python api but I see in your mock example that you specify:
epic_id = epic_key
be careful as in the Jira REST API the two concepts are not the same - the ID of an issue is a numeric identifier while the key is a string (and usually the issue ID you see in the UI).

Anyway i was unable to get a solution usinh atlassian-python api. but i was able to use the rest api end point to search for the epic key and get the items back.
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv


def issues_in_epic(epic_key: str):
    load_dotenv()
    JIRA_URL = os.getenv('JIRA_URL')
    JIRA_USERNAME = os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME')
    JIRA_PASSWORD = os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD')
    url = f'{JIRA_URL}/rest/api/3/search'

    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD)

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }

    query = {
        'jql': f'Parent = {epic_key}'
    }
    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        params=query,
        auth=auth
    )
    response_json = response.json()
    response_json_issues = response_json['issues']


we can loop in response_json['issues'] to get details of individual issues
